# Mysql2::Error - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql2, password-recovery

I am using training software to learn Rails. I am using Windows 7 64bit with Service Pack 1 installed. I have MySQL Server 5.6 installed, along with MySQL Workbench 6.2 CE... if that makes a difference or not.

Right, so I building a content management system in the training and I am on "Accessing a Project" in the training software. I was told to start the server, which I did and everything is running fine. However, when visiting the site in Firefox, I received this error:

---

Mysql2::Error

Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Rails.root: E:/Programming/Rails/Sites/Simple_CMS
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

mysql2-0.3.18-x64 (mingw32) lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `connect'
mysql2-0.3.18-x64 (mingw32) lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in`initialize'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `new'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in`mysql2_connection'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:436:in `new_connection'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:446:in`checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in`block in checkout'
C:/Languages/Ruby/21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in`checkout'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
C:/Languages/Ruby/21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in`mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:565:in`retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in`connection'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:384:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:371:in`call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in`call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in`_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in`call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in`call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.1.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in`call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`call_app'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`tagged'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in`call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in`call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in`call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in`call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in`call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
C:/Languages/Ruby/21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in`service'
C:/Languages/Ruby/21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/Languages/Ruby/21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in`block in start_thread'

Request

```
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: "CGI/1.1"
HTTP_ACCEPT: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: "gzip, deflate"
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: "en-GB,en;q=0.5"
REMOTE_ADDR: "::1"
REMOTE_HOST: "::1"
SERVER_NAME: "localhost"
SERVER_PROTOCOL: "HTTP/1.1"
```

---

Okay, so reading the previous answers, it appears that I have a password error. At first, I couldn't remember the password I assigned so I looked on here for ways to change it. I thought I changed it but apparently I did not. When I added the password to database.yml file, I still get the same error.

Frustrated, I looked at another forum post similar to this one and found I have to use the code:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('somepassword')
```

Well, that isn't working. Maybe I lack the permissions, but I thought root access gave you administrative privileges.

Comment: The MySQL command line? Hmm, have been trying to change my password from the command prompt. I will try again...

Hmm, seems they want a password the moment I click into the MySQL 5.6 Command Line Client. Is there a file I can look at to see what the root password is? If not, what is the procedure for resetting the root password?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the steps [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.0/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html) in order to reset the root password.  There are number of steps.  If it was me and there is nothing that cannot be redone or recovered from a backup on mysql, I would just reinstall from scratch with a fresh root password that I wont forget.

Comment: I literally just got finished doing that. Here is the message I received: 

2015-03-10 21:10:37 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is depreciated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more defaults).

I know you want me to take the easy way out and just reinstall but if I do not learn to handle these situations now, then when I start working for a larger organization, I will be up the creek without a paddle. I am sure "just reinstalling MySQL" will not fly well in a major organization

Comment: I don't have a backup, but fine. I guess I can keep reinstalling everything whenever I have a problem...